# Permission denied (publickey).?

Tags: networking, server, ssh, authentication, openssh

when I'm trying to connect to server get this error

can you help me?

thanks!

ssh root@srv.alimd.ir -vvv

```
OpenSSH_8.8p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1l  24 Aug 2021
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/njfamirm/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/njfamirm/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/njfamirm/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug2: resolving "srv.alimd.ir" port 22
debug3: resolve_host: lookup srv.alimd.ir:22
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to srv.alimd.ir [94.237.24.136] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x48
debug1: Connection established.
..
.
.
.
.
.
.
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/njfamirm/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:nG0n/dYkV6P2wHzjnOXEKe2LjIFWYe9CnZvb7zHljxk
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/njfamirm/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/njfamirm/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/njfamirm/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/njfamirm/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/njfamirm/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug3: no such identity: /home/njfamirm/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/njfamirm/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/njfamirm/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/njfamirm/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug3: no such identity: /home/njfamirm/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/njfamirm/.ssh/id_xmss
debug3: no such identity: /home/njfamirm/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
root@srv.alimd.ir: Permission denied (publickey).
```

~/.ssh/config

```
Host *
    StrictHostKeyChecking ask
    UserKnownHostsFile ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    LogLevel INFO
    ServerAliveInterval 120
```

Comment: You appear to be trying to use *your* RSA private key (`/home/njfamirm/.ssh/id_rsa`) to authenticate as `root` on the server - are you sure it's set up to allow that (i.e. your public key is in *root*'s authorized keys file on the target host)?

Comment: 1) Most public servers forbit logins as the user root. 2) You do not have an SSH key for this server stored in ~/.ssh. You will need to possess the private key for that server to login. You do not have any keys in the default directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems your server requires to connect with ssh key only. This file seems missing on your computer :

```
/home/njfamirm/.ssh/id_dsa
```

You can create a new one with ssh-keygen, but it can be a problem for the existing server as another key is probably already deployed.

Maybe you changed your computer ?